# Override bootstrap less style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have a `main.css`:

```
@import '~bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less';

@import url('./base.css');
@import url('./components/navbar.css');
```

I want to override bootstrap's default body background-color, so I have

```
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

inside `base.css`,

but that does not override bootstrap's property. If I import `~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` instead of `~bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less`, I am able to see my changes, but not with less file. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you really need the `.less` file? Why not use the minified css instead?

Comment: @Swellar because I don't really need all those components in bootstrap. I just need a few of them. So later I'll create my own less file and cherry pick the components I need

Comment: .less needs to be 'build' to be a CSS file so browsers can read them, is the builded CSS also above your custom CSS? Or does that get injected at a different point within your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you cannot import a .less file in a .css file. it has to be converted first.

If you want to import the .less file, you'd have to have a main.less and convert that to .css

You can use GRUNTJS for that.